# How to connect to MQ using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to make a connection & send a string to `MQ` using JAVA.

Following are the MQ details.

- **JNDI Name:**    ABCDEFH
- **Queue Manager:**    ABCDEFH
- **Host Name or IP Address:**  ABCDEFH
- **Port:** ABCDEFH
- **Channel:**  ABCDEFH
- **Transport Type:**   ABCDEFH

I am new to this, so can you please help me with sample code for this. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What kind of MQ are you using? Do you have an API jar?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend you check this link on how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Unfortunately your post (in its current state) isn't a question, you're just asking for code. You'll likely receive downvotes because of this, and nobody wants to write your code for you. However, tons of people are more than willing to help you if you have a specific problem after trying something.

Comment: @llogiq Websphere MQ

Comment: @llogiq I have used the following code http://java-brew.blogspot.in/2011/01/java-code-to-connect-to-mq.html & when I ran i got this error **Socket connection attempt refused**.
Also in the code i dont know what to put in the following fieldsString qMngrStr = "";
    String user = "";
    String password = "";
    String queueName = ""; Can u guide me through this.???

Comment: @AmrinderSingh those are the Strings used for authentication that you pass to MQ. I highly recommend you pick up a book on the basics of Java, or even checking out the official Oracle tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Well, this question is not good in regards of SO standards, but in fact the easiest way for me to move forward, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There are two different APIs you can use to send an MQ message using the Java language. You can use the [MQ Classes for Java](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030730_.htm) and you can use the [JMS API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031950_.htm).

Since you mention JNDI, I suspect you mean the JMS API. However, I will answer for both. You sound like you want some sample code. The IBM MQ product supplies you with sample code to look at.

For the MQ Classes for Java, I suggest you look at `<wmq-installation-directory>\Tools\wmqjava\samples\MQSample.java` - that's the "Hello World" app for the Java classes.

For the JMS interface, I suggest you look at `<wmq-installation-directory>\Tools\jms\samples\JmsProducer.java`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code with some changes:

1.Change the host,port, channel,qName and qManager Name accordingly.

2.For OpenOption use MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT.

Hope this helps.

```
//method to connect and send message to Mq   
public void mqSend(){
  try{

     //Create a Hashtable with required properties
     Hashtable properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
     properties.put("hostname", host);
     properties.put("port", port);
     properties.put("channel", channel); 

     //Create a instance of qManager
     MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManagerName, properties);

     //Connect to the Queue
     MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qname, openOptions);

     //Creating the mqmessage
     MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
     mqMsg.writeString(//My Message); 

     MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

     queue.put(mqMsg,pmo);

     queue.close();
     qMgr.disconnect();
  }catch(MqException mqEx){
     mqEx.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

***Note:: please ignore the typos and formatting as I have typed this using a phone.***